# Scrapping of article 370 from Indian Constitution

Tags: constitution, india, kashmir

The government of India scrapped off article 370 making Jammu and Kashmir an Union Territory. Is it possible on the part of the government to convert any Indian state to a Union Territory?

Comment: If you can amend a constitution, you can do anything, so I'd say yes.

Comment: @Stormblessed don't know about other constitutions but with Indian constitution, even though the parliament has power to amend it, it cannot change the basic structure of the Indian constitution. See [basic structure doctrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kesavananda_Bharati_v._State_of_Kerala)

Comment: Voting to close - You are asking questions on two different subjects: Article 370 and the right of the Union Executive to designate territories. Article 370 doesn't have anything to do with the latter. Also J&K is a special case due to Article 370 where it is doubtful if the Union Executive could exercise its right to designate territories because of the special provisions of Article 370. Please edit and clarify in your question if you are only asking about J&K.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, article 3 of the Indian Constitution accords the parliament to alter the boundaries of a state or union territory.
For this, the state legislature's views are not binding upon the parliament. So, In making state to UT or UT to state or merging a part of state to other state or some other combinations mentioned in the article 3, the parliament has it's own say.

reference: https://www.indiacode.nic.in/bitstream/123456789/15240/1/constitution_of_india.pdf